# Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type nvarchar Error 8115 until SQL Agent runs in the morning

Tags: sql-server, math, overflow, nvarchar, sql-agent

I have an SQL Agent job that runs every 15 minutes from 9:15am to 6pm.

```
DECLARE @db_name varchar(100) 
DECLARE c_db_names CURSOR FOR
SELECT name 
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name NOT IN
('VARIOUS DATABASES HERE')
TRUNCATE TABLE DBDATA.dbo.DATA
OPEN c_db_names

FETCH c_db_names INTO @db_name

WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
BEGIN
  EXEC('
    INSERT INTO DBDATA.dbo.DATA
    SELECT 
      ''' + @db_name + '''
      ,COUNT(*)
      ,MIN(datereq)
    FROM ' + @db_name + '.dbo.TABLE
  ' + 'where lqdone = 0')
  FETCH c_db_names INTO @db_name
END

CLOSE c_db_names
DEALLOCATE c_db_names
```

If there are any results I email them to myself. For some unknown reason to me, for the past two or three weeks I'm unable to run that query before 9:15am in the morning when the SQL Agent starts the job and fails with the error message as per the subject. Every next attempt works just fine, it only fails at 9:15am and earlier if I try to run it manually. Really puzzled and not sure what is happening here.

The datereq field is datetime, db_name is nchar. It fails on the 11th database it checks but I've checked the table and its exactly the same as the other ones.

Any ideas? :)

Comment: what is the data type of datereq ? and how about the matching column in DATA table ?

Comment: They are both (datetime, null).

Comment: How about the other column ? where is the error conversion comming from ?

Comment: DATA Table is: DBName nchar(30), Jobs(nchar(3) and Datreq(datetime, null). TABLE, column I'm querying is just datereq, null. I can run this query thousands of times right now and it works fine but will error as per subject before 9:15am. I think the error is misleading here but just not sure where it fails.

Comment: the `Jobs` column is only `nchar(3)` if you have more than 999 rows in `TABLE` you will hit that error. Why not use `integer` instead of `nchar` since you are doing a `count(*)` . The number of rows in `TABLE` is probably less than 999 now. And is more than 999 at 9:15 am

Comment: The jobs value is usually no more than 10, the whole idea of this is to sort out if the value goes over 2.

Comment: that is the only place i can think off that might gives that error. Other column the data type matches, except the `Jobs` . If you can't change to integer, then try increse the size of the colunn and see if the error still persist